# Getting details of an API call to external service from Python

Tags: python, azure, openai-api

I want to get details (endpoint, parameters etc.) of an API call made from python code to external service. E.g. in code

```
import openai
openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_base = "<your endpoint>"
openai.api_version = "2022-12-01"
openai.api_key = "<your token>"
engine = "test-code"
print(engine, openai.api_type, openai.api_key, openai.api_base, openai.api_version, openai.organization)
codex_query="What is OpenAI?"
response = openai.Completion.create(engine=engine, prompt=codex_query, stop="#")
print (response)
print (response['choices'][0]['text'])
```

I want to check it for the actual call made to Azure Open AI service. The reason I want to do it is because the above standalone script works however when I am doing the same thing from within an opensource that I am trying to enhance it is giving an error of:

> Invalid request - The API deployment for this resource does not exist. If you created the deployment within the last 5 minutes, please wait a moment and try again.

Answer (score 2):

> Invalid request - The API deployment for this resource does not exist. If you created the deployment within the last 5 minutes, please wait a moment and try again.

In your code, you have used **`engine`** but, you need to mention your deployment name. You can get the deployment name using the portal below.

[image]

If you already created a deployment name wait for some time because It seems that it takes a while at preview.

I tried with the same code to change the deployment name into **`deployment1`** it executed successfully.

**Code:**

```
import openai


openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_base = "your-endpoint-name"
openai.api_version = "2022-12-01"
openai.api_key = "your-azure-api-key"
deploymentname = "Deployment1"
print(deploymentname, openai.api_type, openai.api_key, openai.api_base, openai.api_version, openai.organization)
codex_query="What is OpenAI provide me details?"
response = openai.Completion.create(engine=deploymentname, prompt=codex_query,stop="#")
print (response)
print (response['choices'][0]['text'])
```

**Output:**

```
 Deployment1 azure xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx 2022-12-01 None
{
  "id": "cmpl-7adGc6hEbwALupcxxxxxxxxx",
  "object": "text_completion",
  "created": 1688965106,
  "model": "code-davinci-002",
  "choices": [
    {
      "text": "\n\nOpenAI is a artificial intelligence Artificial Intelligence is an art of making",
      "index": 0,
      "finish_reason": "length",
      "logprobs": null
    }
  ],
  "usage": {
    "completion_tokens": 16,
    "prompt_tokens": 7,
    "total_tokens": 23
  }
}


OpenAI is a artificial intelligence Artificial Intelligence is an art of making
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[openai-samples/Basic_Samples/Completions/basic_completions_example_sdk.ipynb at main · Azure/openai-samples · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/openai-samples/blob/main/Basic_Samples/Completions/basic_completions_example_sdk.ipynb)

Comment: I know the different between engine and deployment in case of Azure Open AI. I have taken care of it and my script given here also works. The question is how to get the endpoint and the request details (e.g. json) that get sent to Azure Open AI service. I need it for some other debugging as posted in another question here.